# House plan design (Head First C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, interface, xaml

I've been working through the book Head First C# and this is an exercise from chapter 7, which is about interfaces and abstract classes.

Note that the class design was mandated by the authors, I'm open to suggestions to improve.

I'd like a review on any and all aspects. My code ended up quite a bit different than the book's solution, because it's a few years old and I think "holds back" on newer C#/.NET features and syntax.

In a shared code base, I would include that XML documentation, but since this is just local code for learning, I didn't. Any and all feedback appreciated.

---

The authors' published implementation is [here on GitHub](https://github.com/head-first-csharp/third-edition/tree/master/VS2013/Chapter_7/LetsBuildAHouse). The idea is to implement a floor plan that can be explored, with room connections and doors to the outside. It's done through a WinForms application.

Here is a picture of the plan from the book. Sorry, couldn't find a screenshot.

[image: floorplan]

The app looks like this:

[image: app]

---

#### Location.cs

```
using System;

namespace House
{
    abstract class Location
    {
        public Location(string name) => Name = name;

        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public Location[] Exits;

        public virtual string Description
        {
            get
            {
                string description = $"You're standing in the {Name}. You see exits to the following places: \r\n";
                foreach (Location exit in Exits)
                {
                    description += $"— {exit.Name}";
                    if (exit != Exits[Exits.Length - 1])
                    {
                        description += "\r\n";
                    }
                }
                return description;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Room.cs

```
using System;

namespace House
{
    class Room : Location
    {
        public Room(string name, string decoration) 
            : base(name)
        {
            Decoration = decoration;
        }

        private string Decoration { get; set; }

        public override string Description => $"You see {Decoration}. {base.Description} ";
    }
}
```

#### Outside.cs

```
using System;

namespace House
{
    class Outside : Location
    {
        public Outside(string name, bool hot)
            : base(name)
        {
            Hot = hot;
        }

        private bool Hot { get; }

        override public string Description => Hot 
            ? "It's very hot here. " + base.Description 
            : base.Description;
    }
}
```

---

#### IHasInteriorDoor.cs

```
using System;

namespace House
{
    interface IHasExteriorDoor
    {
        string DoorDescription { get; }
        Location DoorLocation { get; }
    }
}
```

---

#### OutsideWithDoor.cs

```
using System;

namespace House
{
    class OutsideWithDoor : Outside, IHasExteriorDoor
    {
        public OutsideWithDoor(string name, bool hot, string doorDescription)
            : base(name, hot)
        {
            DoorDescription = doorDescription;
        }

        public string DoorDescription { get; private set; }

        public Location DoorLocation { get; set; }

        public override string Description => $"{base.Description}\r\n You see {DoorDescription} to go inside.";
    }
}
```

#### RoomWithDoor.cs

```
using System;

namespace House
{
    class RoomWithDoor : Room, IHasExteriorDoor
    {
        public RoomWithDoor(string name, string decoration, string doorDescription)
            : base(name, decoration)
        {
            DoorDescription = doorDescription;
        }

        public string DoorDescription { get; private set; }

        public Location DoorLocation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

And here is the WinForms to make it work. Leaving out IDE generated code.

#### ExploreTheHouseForm.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace House
{
    public partial class ExploreTheHouseForm : Form
    {
        Location currentLocation;

        RoomWithDoor livingRoom;
        RoomWithDoor kitchen;
        Room diningRoom;
        OutsideWithDoor frontYard;
        OutsideWithDoor backYard;
        Outside garden;

        public ExploreTheHouseForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CreateObjects();
            MoveToLocation(livingRoom);
        }

        private void CreateObjects()
        {
            // Configure the locations
            livingRoom = new RoomWithDoor("living room", "an antique carpet", "an oak door with a brass knob");
            kitchen = new RoomWithDoor("kitchen", "stainless steel appliances", "a screen door");
            diningRoom = new Room("dining room", "a crystal chandelier");
            frontYard = new OutsideWithDoor("front yard", false, livingRoom.DoorDescription);
            backYard = new OutsideWithDoor("back yard", true, kitchen.DoorDescription);
            garden = new Outside("garden", false);

            // Configure the exits
            livingRoom.Exits = new Location[] { diningRoom };
            kitchen.Exits = new Location[] { diningRoom };
            diningRoom.Exits = new Location[] { livingRoom, kitchen };
            frontYard.Exits = new Location[] { backYard, garden };
            backYard.Exits = new Location[] { frontYard, garden };
            garden.Exits = new Location[] { frontYard, backYard };

            // Configure exterior doors
            livingRoom.DoorLocation = frontYard;
            frontYard.DoorLocation = livingRoom;
            kitchen.DoorLocation = backYard;
            backYard.DoorLocation = kitchen;
        }

        private void MoveToLocation(Location location)
        {
            currentLocation = location;
            ExitsComboBox.Items.Clear();
            foreach (Location exit in location.Exits)
            {
                ExitsComboBox.Items.Add(exit.Name);
            }
            ExitsComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
            DescriptionTextBox.Text = currentLocation.Description;
            ShowGoThroughExteriorDoorButton(currentLocation);
        }

        private void ShowGoThroughExteriorDoorButton(Location location)
        {
            if (location is IHasExteriorDoor)
            {
                GoThroughExteriorDoorButton.Visible = true;
                return;
            }
            GoThroughExteriorDoorButton.Visible = false;
        }

        private void GoHereButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MoveToLocation(currentLocation.Exits[ExitsComboBox.SelectedIndex]);
        }

        private void GoThroughExteriorDoorButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IHasExteriorDoor locationWithExteriorDoor = currentLocation as IHasExteriorDoor;
            MoveToLocation(locationWithExteriorDoor.DoorLocation);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The winforms screen gives the option to go through the exterior door, but whatever is behind the exterior door doesn't get listed in the available places? What happens if the kitchen had multiple exterior doors to multiple places? What if the entire house was just a kitchen?

Comment: If you are interested in the general problem of how to write text-based adventures, I encourage you to look into `Inform7`, an exceedingly clever language for writing such adventures. If you're interested in learning about virtual machines for implementing such adventures, I did a series on my blog a few years ago about the Z-machine.

Comment: As a bonus, on a Z-machine code for this problem will occupy less than a kilobyte. You won't be able to compile the above code into a .NET assembly that takes up that much. (This is another way of saying "in Ye Olde Days we didn't have no interfaces and abstract classes". However, we were also much more likely to be eaten by a grue, so it all evens out in the end.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[RobH's review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/211671/16504) covers syntax and style well so I won't go into that. Instead I'd like to give my take on feedback given by [Svek](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/211704/16504) and [BittermanAndy](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/211716/16504).

### Separation Of Concerns

I think Svek's commentary about the `CreateObjects` method is spot on, but I don't think it goes far enough. The need for such a method in the first place hints that the `ExploreTheHouseForm` class is doing to much. With the current implementation, each of the rooms is a field on the form. This effectively makes the `ExploreTheHouseForm` the house itself. As such it would be more aptly named `ExplorableHouseForm`.

In general (and this becomes ever more important as you get into more complex projects) we want to separate the presentation of the data from the data itself.

The form *is the UI* it already has the duty to present the data to the user. It shouldn't also *be the data*. I would much rather the house be constructed elsewhere and passed to the form's constructor:

```
    public ExploreTheHouseForm(Location initialRoom)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MoveToLocation(initialRoom);
    }
```

With this simple change, you can remove all the individual `Location` fields from `ExploreTheHouseForm` with the exception of `currentLocation`. Also, if you desire, you can use the same form to explore any number of different houses without further modification.

### Immutability

A fair amount of BittermanAndy's advice (as of the time of this writing, his post was updated at least once since I started) was to try to make your `Location` class immutable. Since with the overall design as it is, locations need to reference each other, you run into a chicken & egg scenario preventing immutability where each `Location` needs their neighbors to be created before them. I don't see a way around this, however if you have your locations implement an interface, and write your form to consume the interface rather than `Location` you can get much of the same benefit of actual immutability.

```
public interface ILocation
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public IList<ILocation> Exits {get;}
    public string Description { get;}
}
```

In `ILocation` we only specify the `get` portions of the properties. This means to consumers of `ILocation` the properties are effectively read-only even if the implementing classes implement the `set`. We also declare `Exits` as a collection of `ILocation` rather than `Location` so that accessed members are also read-only to consumers.

You don't have to change much about `Location` itself:

```
public abstract class Location: ILocation
{
    ...
    //private field to back Exits property. 
    private IList<ILocation> _exits;

    public IList<ILocation> Exits {
       get
       {
           // AsReadOnly so that consumers are not allowed to modify contents.
           // there are other ways of accomplishing this that may be better overall, but ExploreTheHouseForm accesses Exits by index so we can only change it so much. 
           return _exits?.AsReadOnly();
       }
       set{ _exits = value;}
    }
}
```

Updating `ExploreTheHouseForm` is also straight forward, simply change the type of the field `currentLocation` the `Location` parameters of `ExploreTheHouseForm`, `MoveToLocation`, and `ShowGoThroughExteriorDoorButton` to `ILocation`:

```
    ...
    private ILocation _currentLocation;
    ...
    public ExploreTheHouseForm(ILocation initialRoom)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MoveToLocation(initialRoom);
    }
    ...
    private void MoveToLocation(ILocation location)
    ... 
    private void ShowGoThroughExteriorDoorButton(ILocation location)
```

The overall impact of this is that the locations are mutable during construction (by some factory) but once construction is complete, all you work with the read-only `ILocation`

```
// GenerateHouse returns the entry point of the house.

public ILocation GenerateHouse()
{
    // Configure the locations
    var livingRoom = new RoomWithDoor("living room", "an antique carpet", "an oak door with a brass knob");
    var kitchen = new RoomWithDoor("kitchen", "stainless steel appliances", "a screen door");
    var diningRoom = new Room("dining room", "a crystal chandelier");
    var frontYard = new OutsideWithDoor("front yard", false, livingRoom.DoorDescription);
    var backYard = new OutsideWithDoor("back yard", true, kitchen.DoorDescription);
    var garden = new Outside("garden", false);

    // Configure the exits
    livingRoom.Exits = new List<ILocation>() { diningRoom };
    kitchen.Exits = new List<ILocation>() { diningRoom };
    diningRoom.Exits = new List<ILocation> { livingRoom, kitchen };
    frontYard.Exits = new List<ILocation> { backYard, garden };
    backYard.Exits = new List<ILocation> { frontYard, garden };
    garden.Exits = new List<ILocation> { frontYard, backYard };

    // Configure exterior doors
    livingRoom.DoorLocation = frontYard;
    frontYard.DoorLocation = livingRoom;
    kitchen.DoorLocation = backYard;
    backYard.DoorLocation = kitchen;
    // return entry point.
    return livingRoom;

}
```

### Location Connectivity

I agree with the other reviews and comments that pulling the concept of the location connection into a separate class/set of classes would allow for a better design. Locations can have any number of exits, and it is a property of the exit, not the location if that exit is an open archway, a door, or just an abstract dividing line (outdoor location to outdoor location) Comintern does a good job of covering this in [their review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/211727/16504) so I won't go into it further.

Comment: Excellent answer. Separating the creation of the house, and presenting the form only with the interface it needs for navigation, solves the creation / immutability problem very nicely. (My edits were fairly minor, by the way).

Comment: "there are other ways of accomplishing this that may be better overall, but ExploreTheHouseForm accesses Exits by index so we can only change it so much.". At the very least I don't see any reason to not simply change the return value to `IReadOnlyList` which makes the intent much clearer. Admittedly the better fix for the consumer would be to use IImmutableList from the immutable collections package which really guarantees that the content of the list won't change.

Answer (score 23):

I have a general rule: if I see string concatenation with a loop I assume it's not the best way of doing it. Let's look at this:

```
foreach (Location exit in Exits)
{
    description += $"— {exit.Name}";
    if (exit != Exits[Exits.Length - 1])
    {
        description += "\r\n";
    }
}
```

I see this pattern a lot. What you need is `Select` with `string.Join`:

```
var exitList = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Exits.Select(exit => $"— {exit.Name}"));
```

I've used `Environment.NewLine` because I like using well-named constants. Random aside: `\r` is a Carriage Return and `\n` is a Line Feed. The terminology comes from physical printers. Another reason I prefer `Environment.NewLine` is that it means you don't have to know and remember that.

**Edit**

A comment notes that `Environment.NewLine` is different on Windows vs Linux/Unix. I think that's important to know and I really should have mentioned it the first time. As the comment exchange shows, it's really easy to get platforms and line-endings mixed up which I think illustrates the usefulness of the constant.

---

The `Name` property of `Location` is only set in the constructor. You can use a read-only auto property instead of a private set one:

```
public string Name { get; }
```

---

`Outside.Description` could be using string interpolation like the other Description properties.

---

You're missing your access modifiers on your class declarations. MS guidelines state that they should always be specified.

---

I'm not aware of a convention for it but `override public string` seems to be an odd order to me. I would expect the access modifier first: `public override string`. The main thing is to keep that consistent though.

Comment: `Environment.NewLine` is better for working with Windows or Linux because it contains a different value depending on the OS.  For Windows, `Environment.NewLine` is "\r\n" and on Linux, it is "\r", but by using `Environment.NewLine` you do not need to worry about those details.

Comment: @RickDavin - yes, that's true. I think that `\r` was old mac though, no? Unix/linux use `\n` AFAIK.

Comment: My mistake.  Yes Linux is "\n".  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015766/difference-between-n-and-environment-newline

Answer (score 10):

You've already made a decent effort to **make your types immutable** by setting its properties in a constructor and providing get-only access, not set - like you have with `Location.Name` for example. This is good practice whenever it is reasonable to do so (because, among other things, this means you can pass objects around without ever worrying that something else will change their state unexpectedly). However, I note that `Location.Exits` is a public field, which means it could be replaced with another array while the program is running - but the house is supposed to be fixed in structure. It would be better as a get-only public property, passed as another parameter in the constructor.

More subtly, not only could someone do something like `currentLocation.Exits = ...`, which the above advice would prevent; someone could also do `currentLocation.Exits[0] = ...`, and again they are changing something that is supposed to be fixed. (When I say "someone", understand that that could mean "you, by mistake", especially in a larger more complex program). Since you mentioned you have been learning about **interfaces**, the public get accessor for `Location.Exits` should be an `IEnumerable<Location>`, which lets things enumerate through the exits array to see what they are, but not change them. (*If you've not used generics yet, don't worry too much about this for now*).

So it would end up like this:

```
abstract class Location
{
    public Location(string name, Location[] exits)
    {
        Name = name;
        _exits = exits;
    }

    public string Name { get; }

    private Location[] _exits;
    public IEnumerable<Location> Exits => _exits;

    // ...
}
```

(*Secretly, I'm not super-happy about passing in exits as an array, either. Again, someone could change that array after creating the `Location`. I'd rather pass in exits as an `IEnumerable<Location>` and copy them into a new array or other container type private to the `Location`. But that raises some design and object ownership questions that aren't too relevant here so let's not worry about that*).

---

Digging deeper on locations/exits - a couple of things here, which are probably too large a change to worry about for this exercise, but something to think about in future.

Firstly, `OutsideWithDoor` inherits from `Outside` and implements the `IHasExteriorDoor` interface. This works for your purposes, but means the question of whether or not an exit from one location to the next has a door depends on the type of the locations, whereas logically speaking it's a property of the connection between them. (It's also limited to only one door per location, and a few other tricky bits - **prefer to avoid unnecessary inheritance**, and **prefer composition over inheritance**). So, I would suggest a `LocationConnection` type, where `Location`s are joined by `LocationConnection`s rather than directly to other `Location`s, and a `LocationConnection` can either have a door or not (a boolean property).

Secondly, `Location` exits are bi-directional, that is, if you can go from one location to another, you can always go back, too. That makes sense (if you go from the kitchen to the dining room, it'd be very odd to be unable to go back to the kitchen!) but depends on your initialization code always getting that right, which is a common source of bugs. (What if the building was a mansion, with a hundred rooms!?) This problem could go away if that `LocationConnection` type were well-implemented, someone could travel along it in either direction and it only needs to be coded once. Something to bear in mind in future: **whenever you have to remember to write BA if you write AB, someone's going to forget to do it**. Make their (your) lives easier!

Introducing that new type may be a bigger change than is really justified for this code review, but it could solve a couple of potential problems.

---

A couple of very minor comments on `ShowGoThroughExteriorDoorButton`. Firstly, the name of the method is OK, but it sounds like it's *always* going to show that button. I'd call it `ShowOrHide...`, though that's just my personal preference. Also, the if-statement in that method is a bit inelegant. I'd write simply:

```
GoThroughExteriorDoorButton.Visible = (location is IHasExteriorDoor);
```

...which gets rid of those naked `true` and `false` values, and also gets rid of that ugly `return` halfway through the method. In general, **prefer methods to have a single point of exit, at the end**, though this isn't always practical, especially when you start to use exceptions.

---

Always specify **access modifiers**, especially `private` for all those fields on the `ExploreTheHouseForm`. Also, a common convention for **private fields** is to prefix them with an underscore, e.g. `private Location _currentLocation;`, though this is not universally followed - I like it because it helps make obvious what's a parameter or local variable, and what's a member variable.

Comment: The desire to have the `Location` immutable and take the exits in the constructor is great, but it seems incompatible with two-way travel. The kitchen has an exit to the dining room, and the dining room has an exit to to the kitchen. In order to follow your implementation advice, both would have to be created before the other. The proposed `LocationConnection` class seems to have the same chicken and egg problem preventing immutability. It will have to reference the locations it connects, and they will have to reference it. How would you resolve this conflict?

Comment: Fair point. One possible solution would be to create the Locations without exit information, then create a list/LUT of LocationConnections. The Location then wouldn't itself hold references to its exits - every time it wanted to know, it would have to check the LocationConnection list. Is that better or worse than just allowing the Location class to be mutable? It becomes a judgement call at that point and depends on how the classes will be used. Mutable is great "whenever it is reasonable to do so"... it isn't always.

Comment: Very interesting answer, thank you! I'll be taking this into consideration in the future!

Comment: Comintern's (good) answer provides some examples of what the exit/connection types might look like.

Comment: @MrMindor The usual way around this (apart from redesigning to avoid circular references) is to use a builder pattern during creation which is mutable and generate immutable classes from that one.

Answer (score 7):

The other reviews covered many of the main points I'd raise, but there are a handful of others.

---

Constructors in abstract classes should be `protected`, not `public`:

> ```
> public Location(string name) => Name = name;
> ```

You can't create a new instance of the abstract class, so it is for all intents and purposes `protected` anyway.  Make the access modifier match the behavior.

---

I'm not sure that I like some of the naming. For example, `CreateObjects()` gives only the slightest clue as to what it is doing. I'd probably go with something more along the lines of `GenerateMap()`. A couple of the member names are also a little ambiguous as to how they function - for example, which room is `IHasExteriorDoor.DoorLocation` relative to?

---

Speaking of doors (keeping in mind that I'm not sure how much was proscribed by the exercise), I also think I find it a bit more natural to have the exits be the primary motive object.  It's more natural to me to think of "using a door" than it is to think of "leaving a room".  To me, a room is a static thing - it ***has*** exits, but you don't really use a room by leaving it.  I'd consider building your map from the standpoint of the connections between the locations instead of the locations themselves. Something more like this:

```
public interface ILocation
{
    string Name { get; }
    string Description { get; }
}
```

---

```
public interface IExit
{
    // TODO: my naming sucks too.
    ILocation LocationOne { get; }
    ILocation LocationTwo { get; }
    // Takes the room you're exiting as a parameter, returns where you end up.
    ILocation Traverse(ILocation from);
}
```

---

```
public abstract class Location : ILocation
{
    private readonly IReadOnlyList<IExit> _exits;

    protected Location(string name, string description, IEnumerable<IExit> exits)
    {
        _exits = exits.ToList();
    }

    public IEnumerable<IExit> Exits => _exits;

    // ...other properties...
}
```

That lets you concentrate on the spatial relationships between the locations from a more natural direction (IMO and no pun intended). You'll likely find this to be more easily extensible down the road when you need to, say close or lock a door:

```
public interface Door : IExit
{
    bool IsOpen { get; }
    bool IsLocked { get; }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have both a `ILocation` interface and a `Location` abstract class? Since you have the `Location` abstract class I'd prefer to move `Name` and `Description` to `Location` as abstract properties.

Comment: @inwenis That would fall under the `// ...other properties...` comment. The example `Location` was intended to highlight the `Exits`.

Comment: I've read other reviwes and seems the `ILocation` can be used to pass locations as immutable objects. It's nice but without any comments I would recommennd mering them. OK, maybe now after I have seen what it can be used for I would have my doubts.

Answer (score 6):

In this code block here:

```
...
OutsideWithDoor backYard;
Outside garden;

public ExploreTheHouseForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    CreateObjects(); // <--- bleh
    MoveToLocation(livingRoom);
}
```

This is call to the `CreateObject()` method, is something I don't like to see in code (it could be a personal style issue) but if you are constructing an object, then all code related to the construction of an object should just stay in the constructor...

I would prefer that it ended up looking like

```
...
private readonly OutsideWithDoor _backYard;  // now it can be readonly
private readonly Outside _garden;

public ExploreTheHouseForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ...
    _backYard = new OutsideWithDoor("back yard", true, kitchen.DoorDescription);
    _garden = new Outside("garden", false);

    MoveToLocation(livingRoom);
}
```

Comment: "all code related to the construction of an object should just stay in the constructor" I have the disagree with that. If it's a one-liner? Do it inline - no point creating helper methods. But for more complex initializations separating logically independent parts into their own methods keeps methods small, simple and self-documenting. Otherwise we end up with a giant constructor method that requires comments to separate the different parts. Now you certainly do want to keep things readonly, but the usual solution is to simply return the created object and assign it in the constructor.